# Scipy Stats.describe and Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm exploring the college.csv dataset and getting descriptive stats for each column, and it works if I drop the two categorical columns.

```
college = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Temple/ISLR_Datasets/College.csv")
from scipy import stats
college = college.drop("Unnamed: 0", 1)
college = college.drop("Private", 1)

for col in college.columns:
  desc[col] = stats.describe(college[col])
```

But if I try to just ignore the columns and keep the dataset in tact it throws an operand type error:

```
for col in college.columns:
  if(col!="Unnamed: 0" or col!="Private"):
    desc[col] = stats.describe(college[col])

unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Any ideas what pandas or numpy is doing differently?

Comment: What's the `College.csv` dataset? What is `col` exactly when the exception is raised?

Comment: When you report a Python error, always include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the full error message).  It will show which line actually raised the exception.  (In this case, I suspect it is in the call `stats.describe(college[col])`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is at the `if condition`, it cannot ignore the columns `"Unnamed: 0"` and `"Private"`, it will always be True. The `stats.describe(college[col])` will apply on columns `"Unnamed: 0"` and `"Private"`. You can use `not in string list` instead to filter them:

```
if col not in ["Unnamed: 0","Private"]
```

Comment: Thanks, just a simple oversight!